# About DPI issue

Tags: windows, winapi, dpi

I have a WIN32 SW which the UI was designed in 96 DPI, so when user changes the windows DPI from 96 to 120 or bigger, the UI will be wrong. I want to know if there is API to force my SW to display the UI with 96DPI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with Windows Vista, scaling for DPI is supposed to happen automatically.  I don't have any direct experience to know how well it works, but here's the page that explains how to turn it off:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms701681(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can also add an appcompat key for your application. The place for this in the registry is:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers`

That is the per-user settings, there is the same key in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, but of course that is a system setting and will require elevated privileges to write to. Adding a key like so:

`"C:\path\to\app.exe"="HIGHDPIAWARE"`

Will enable that compatibility flag for your program, which will turn off DPI scaling. This is for Vista+.

[SetProcessDPIAware](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633543.aspx) is also an option, but be aware there is a danger of a race condition, according to the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API to force your app to show at 96DPI. The DPI is a device setting and cannot be controlled per application.

If you can change your program, you can scale your UI to look properly on high DPI though. You need to call [`GetDeviceCaps`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144877(VS.85).aspx); more specificaly, you need to calculate the X and Y scale using the number returned for `LOGPIXELSX` and `LOGPIXELSY`. Something like this:

```
HDC hdc;
double m_dDPIScaleX = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSX) / 96.0;
double m_dDPIScaleY = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSY) / 96.0;
```