# Winform - Display

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a c# winform project which is displaying much different on my screen from the server.

On my screen I am getting parts of the forms  cut off and some controls in different areas. I have adjusted my resolution both to the same resolution and mine greater then the server. Neither one worked.  Also, the fonts and controls look larger on the server despite the same resolution

Any Ideas?

The server build is using VS.net 2008 vs mine 2010.  I dont think that should matter.

Comment: Start by comparing the same Builds.

Comment: Different OS and/or different OS theme ?

Comment: Is it possible that it's a [font size](http://www.techtalkz.com/windows-7/516049-how-change-font-size-icon-size-windows-7-a.html) issue? Do you have both systems set to 72 or 96 dpi?

Comment: may be server doesnt support visual styles

Comment: Thanks Everyone. I was the DPI setting which is now the same as the server.  That was driving my crazy.  Luckily I dont have to program for the differences since it is resides on the terminal server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like different DPI settings between the machines.  I noticed this when I first created a project in Win7 and ran it on a WinXP machine.  Here is [an SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572820/c-scaling-usercontrol-content-to-match-users-dpi-font-size) describing the issue and how to fix it.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like your server has a different DPI setting than your machine. Developing for different DPI settings with Winforms can be a real pain, since Winforms AutoScaleMode-Feature has some quirks. See, for example this former post of mine:

[AutoScaleMode problems with changed default font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973165/autoscalemode-problems-with-changed-default-font)