# Screen Text size in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to know if the text size is at 125% from .NET/C#?

The setting comes from Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display ...

Comment: Do you want to know text size or DPI? (http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/14/182971.aspx) If you do need to know text size, do you just need to know if it's 125%, or what the actual size is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven´t tried this my self.

This registry key in windows pre Windows 7:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontDPI:LogPixels

And this one in Windows 7:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop:LogPixels

All according to this thread in [MSDN Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/csharpgeneral/thread/aba95854-faa5-4dea-afd4-262380966938)

Here is some additional resources:
[Creating a DPI-Aware Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms701681.aspx)
[C# Scaling UserControl content to match users Dpi/Font Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572820)
[About DPI issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572270)

Comment: I was abl to get the correct value using HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\LogPixels. The value is 96 when using 100% and 120 when using 125%. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but maybe you can just get the Dpi settings and check if they're 96 or not:

```
using(Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
{
    MessageBox.Show(g.DpiX.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + g.DpiY.ToString());
}
```

You might have to call `SetProcessDPIAware` first though.